# Using SSL on two VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, ssl, subdomain, virtualhost, vhosts

So I got an SSL from GoDaddy.
It works for my public site `mysite.com`.
I would like now to have an SSL connection for my `administrator.mysite.com`
So I created a self signed certificate using **`openssl`** because I don't mind managing my own site with a red mark on the lock.

inside **`httpd-ssl.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mysite.com:443
   ServerAlias www.mysite.com

   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/

   ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com

   ErrorLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_errors.log
   TransferLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_access.log

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/mysite.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/server_nopwd.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/gd_bundle.crt

   SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
   CustomLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </FilesMatch>
   <Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>                                  

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName administrator.mysite.com:443
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"

   ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com

   ErrorLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_errors_admin.log
   TransferLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_access_admin.log

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/admin.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/admin.key

   SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
   CustomLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/MySite/logfiles/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

And I get this warning:

```
[warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
```

What happens is that the administrator host is redirected to the regular host, which is very annoying

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Strangely some report it works for them like a charm but for others not. I even tried using SNI via *SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck* apache directive but no luck.

When using the *ServerAlias* directive with a wildcard domain like eg. **.snakeoil.com* then order of the *VirtualHost* configs matters. If the *VirtualHost* with the wildcard domain alias:

```
ServerAlias *.snakeoil.com
```

is the first one it will be processed first and avoids resolution of other vhosts. Try to reverse vhosts so that this catch all is the last one eg.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

# first vhost
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName vhost1.snakeoil.com
    [...]
</VirtualHost>

# second vhost
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName vhost2.snakeoil.com
    [...]
</VirtualHost>

# Attention!
# All other vhost requests end up here
# Order matters, keep this entry to be the last one
# as a last resort if any of the above don't apply
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName snakeoil.com
    ServerAlias *.snakeoil.com
    [...]
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Worked for me at least with with *apache 2.2.14*

Comment: This worked for me, Windows, Apache 2.4, Wildcard SSL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine for newer browsers, although it might be worth checking your htaccess rules incase one of them is inadvertently redirecting `admin.mysite.com` to `mysite.com`.

The warning message you're getting is explained more here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI (essentially older browsers can only view the default virtualhost).